# Not working back button logic when scroll but dont click document in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need that when a client enters the site, an anchor is added to the address bar (let's call it the first anchor), after if he clicks or scrolls, we add another anchor (let's call it the second anchor). After the appearance of the second anchor, if the client presses the browser's "back" button, we go to the first anchor by history and show him a popup. The click logic works successfully. The scrolling logic does not work - the client immediately leaves the site without getting to the page with the first anchor.

This is my part code for ths logic:

```
var isStartUserAction = false;
window.location.href = methods.setAnchor(settings.initAnchor);

$(document).on('touchend', function () {
      if (!isStartUserAction) {
          window.location.href = methods.setAnchor(settings.startLogicAnchor);
          isStartUserAction = true;
      }
}).on('scroll', function () {
      if (!isStartUserAction) {
          window.location.href = methods.setAnchor(settings.startLogicAnchor);
          isStartUserAction = true;
      }
});

window.onpopstate = function(event) {
   if (isStartUserAction && !isShowedModal) {
      methods.show();
   }
};
```

Any ideas?

Comment: scroll logic work in Firefox, in chrome on desctop or mobile not work

Answer (score 0):

Solve the problem when use onhashchange event instead of onpopstate

Comment: Incorrect answer. Don't watch